# Deleting a timestamp range of data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database and I want to delete data for a particular range of timestamps, but not anything from before that range even if it falls on the same day.

For example I want to delete data in the range `2015-03-09 05:09:21` to `2015-03-09 08:09:21` but I want to ensure that data from before `2015-03-09 05:09:21` survives.

Comment: `delete from blah where timestamp_field between 'earliest time' and 'latest time'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I cleaned up your question to make it shorter and clearer, and added a bit of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BETWEEN`-operator in the `WHERE`-clause:

`DELTE FROM my_table WHERE my_timestamp_field BETWEEN 'start time' AND 'end time'`